# Losing Route data in RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoaction, data-loss

hi i have a weird problem and here we go:

i am redirecting using this command :

`return RedirectToAction("ViewMessage", "Account", new {id = model.MessageId});`

but in ViewMessage action when i try to get id, its null ?!?!?!?!??

`string strMessageId = RouteData.Values["id"] as string;`

i have done this code in lots of places and it works fine but i dont know what is going on here.... :(

i know i can use TempData but i dont want to :)

Comment: Does your action ViewMessage take id argument?

Comment: yes, actually first i view the message using id, then i post the reply message to ReplyMessage action, and from action when i try to come back to viewmessage action i get the id null. the cool thing is if i use @html.actionlink("view", "viewmessage", "account", new {id = xxxxxxxx}, null) i can get to message :)

Comment: did you ever work this one out (I'm having a similar issue)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the way you did worked for me still
Try This

---

```
return RedirectToAction("ViewMessage",new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller="Account",action="ViewMessage", id = model.MessageId }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the route value using the View Context

```
ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("id")
```

Comment: compiler says : "can not access non-static property 'RequestContext' in a static context" on the other hand i told you i am using same code sniped in other places and works fine, but thanks for quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your routing configuration. If your action parameter name is "id" then your routing url pattern should be {controller}/{action}/{id}.